# How to copy-and-paste multiple classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to copy-and-paste two Java classes into a new single Eclipse Java Project.  I have created the new project and then right-clicked on that project name in the package explorer.

Then I created a new class with the copy-and-pasted material for CashRegister.  I then right-clicked the project name and make another new class called CashRegisterTester and copy-and-pasted the material I want in there.

I get the normal-looking hierarchy in the package explorer, but CashRegisterTester can't see the methods in CashRegister (and yes, I checked to make sure they are public).

How do people cut-and-paste multiple classes within Eclipse?

Comment: ... How the classes are created is irrelevant. I'd be more suspicious about your project's setup.

Comment: You can just drop them into the folders you want them to appear in in the project in your workspace directory, then do everyone's favorite eclipse move and press F5...

Answer (score 1):

> How do people cut-and-paste multiple classes within Eclipse?

I usually use ctrl + click to multiple select, then crtl + drag/drop to copy the classes to a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your package structure and make sure that it lines up. Maybe you're missing import statements?